# buffer textures in Opengl ES 3.0

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I am writing in GL ES 3.0 and i need to write a vertex shader that can access the attributes of other vertices (identified by their index). The attributes of the vertices may change from frame to frame.
Buffer textures would have been ideal but as far as i can tell they are not implemented in GL ES 3.0.
Is there another way to do this? other than render all my attributes to textures every frame which would be a huge performance penalty.

Comment: You could consider a Uniform Buffer Object instead. That is core in ES 3.0. Unfortunately, they generally cannot store anywhere near as much data as a buffer texture could, but you can index them dynamically in a vertex shader. Just make sure you understand the rules that apply to aligning buffer object memory if you go this route. Chances are if you tried to use the contents of a plain old VBO as a UBO for this purpose, some of the data would be misaligned (particularly if you have any 3-component attributes).

Comment: unfortunately the uniform buffers would be too small for me as i would a minimum of 200k vertices with 8 floats worth of attributes that i would need access to. my application is similar to a particle system.
i found out that ES 3.1 has extensions to buffer texture so i need to check if and when that will be supported on ios

Comment: I re-visited this question, and I think you might be able to use Transform Feedback for this (*core* in ES 3.0). Basically, you would write the results of the vertex shader into a buffer object each frame and since it is all GPU-side, the penalty for doing this is minimal - you can turn around and use the resultant transform feedback buffer object as a vertex buffer object the next frame. That is what you are ultimately trying to do here, right? *Persistent particle information?*